N-factor of Na2S2O3 in reaction with NaOH and NaOCl
The problem requires the normality of a $\pu{25 ml}$ solution $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ that reacts (no remainder, basic environment) with a $\pu{50 ml}$ solution $\pu{0.1 M}$ of hypochlorite $(\ce{OCl^-})$ during which is formed sulfate$(\ce{SO4^{2-}})$ and chloride$(\ce{Cl^{-}})$.
Therefore I suggest this equation:
$$\ce{Na2S2O3 + 2 NaOH + 4 NaOCl -> 4 NaCl + 2 Na2SO4 + H2O}$$
To find normality I would need the n-factor and afterwards amount of substance of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ which multiplied and divided by $V$ would yield normality.
My question here is, what's the n-factor? I approached it like this:
$$\ce{S^{+2}-> S^{+6}}$$
Where oxidation change is $\ce{4e-}$:
$$\ce{2Na+ = 4 e-}$$
$$\ce{Na+ = 2 e-}$$
So I would assume that the n-factor here is 2, meaning:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{N}&=n\cdot M\\
\mathbb{N}&=2\cdot M\\
\mathbb{N}&=2\cdot \frac{n}{V}
\end{align}
Where $n$ can easily be found, since we have everything needed to:
$$n = \pu{50ml}\cdot \frac{\pu{1L}}{\pu{1000ml}}\cdot \frac{\pu{0.1 mol} \ce{OCl^{-}}}{\pu{1L}}\cdot \frac{\pu{1 mol} \ce{Na2S2O3}}{\pu{4mol} \ce{OCl-}} = 0.00125$$
And I end up with the following answer:
$$\mathbb{N}=2\cdot \frac{125\cdot 10^{-5}}{25\cdot 10^{-3}}=2\cdot 25\cdot 10^{-2}=50\cdot 10^{-2}=5\cdot 10^{-1}=0.5$$
Correct in any place?

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

E.g. write $\ce{H2SO4}$ to get $\ce{H2SO4}$ // $\ce{4 Fe^2+ + O2  + 4 H+ -> 4 Fe^3+ + 2 H2O}$ for $\ce{4 Fe^2+ + O2  + 4 H+ -> 4 Fe^3+ + 2 H2O}$ // $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ for $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$

Note that normality is in many cases reaction dependent. It is highly recommended to avoid it, as it may lead to confusion.

Therefore whoever gave you such question is wasting your time, likely using a textbook taken from bygone century.

I've tried to rescue the formatting, but the formulae didn't make much sense to me. What do you even mean with $\ce{2 Na+ = 4 e-}$? Units also aren't just there for decoration, they should be used and not left out. Please do not use MathJax as a way to style text. And lastly, I publicly want to complain that we have yet another question about a long forgotten concept. I'm really sorry for you, that you have to learn this stuff.

Note that the normality and the N-factor are the obsolete concepts, that were abandoned due ambiguity and should be avoided. But they are still taught in some countries and required at respective exams, together with other terms obsolete for decades.

You can write the reaction
$$\ce{Na2S2O3 + 2 NaOH + 4 NaOCl -> 4 NaCl + 2 Na2SO4 + H2O}$$
as:
$$\ce{S2O3^2- + 10 OH- -> 2 SO4^2- + 5 H2O + 8 e-}$$
$$\ce{4 ClO- + 8 e- + 4 H2O -> 4 Cl- + 8 OH- }$$
giving the summary reaction
$$\ce{S2O3^2- + 4 ClO- + 2 OH- -> 2 SO4^2- + 4 Cl- + H2O }$$
$\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ reacts with $\pu{4 mol}$ of $\ce{NaClO}$, but with exchange of 8 electrons, what is the essential information. The ratio of normality/molarity is redox reaction context is equal to the number of exchanged electrons per 1 molecule/ion.
Therefore, N-factor for $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ is 8.
$\pu{25 mL}$ of $\pu{0.05 M}$ $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ reacts with $\pu{50 mL}$ of $\pu{0.1 M NaClO}$, giving the ratio $1 : 2\times 2$.
The normality of $\pu{0.05 M}$ $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ for iodometric reactions is $\pu{0.05 N}$, as $\ce{2 Na2S2O3 + I2 -> Na2S4O6 + 2NaI}$ and 1 electron per $\ce{1 S2O3^2-} is exchanged$.
But for the reaction with hypochlorite with 8-electron exchange, the normality of $\pu{0.05 M}$ $\ce{Na2S2O3}$it is $\pu{0.05 M \times 8}  = \pu{0.4 N}$.
Normality of $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{NaClO}$ is $\pu{0.2 N}$, as $\ce{1 ClO-}$ exchanges 2 electrons.

Feedback comments:
It is simple arithmetic, based on balancing atoms of particular kinds and elementary charges. It is for starters somewhat obfuscated by the special syntax of notation of chemical reactions.
For the enumeration, you can use this heuristics:
If the oxidized particle requires oxygen atoms, then in basic solution it is taken from $\ce{OH-}$, forming $\ce{H2O}$. In acidic solution, it is taken from $\ce{H2O}$, forming $\ce{H3O+}$. For near neutral pH, it depends on the particular overall reaction, both ways are possible.
Above, you see $\ce{1 S2O3^2-}$ requires $\ce{5 O}$, takend from $\ce{10 OH-}$, forming $\ce{5 H2O}$. similarly, $\ce{1 ClO-}$ gives $\ce{1 O}$ to $\ce{1 H2O}$ to form $\ce{2 OH-}$
When all is balanced but electrons, these are explicitly listed as coming or leaving.
You can imagine that such redox half-reactions can occur at respective electrodes during electrolysis, where the electrodes are donors/acceptors of electrons. At ordinary reactions electrons or ions are being exchanged in-place.
You may find useful reviewing these search results site:libretexts.org "redox reactions".

How do you approach this? How did you come up with the idea of having $8{e-}$ and made that reaction? Asking for future problems I will have.

The answer has been updated.
